# VS2022 solution with 2 web apis; running the 2nd uses appsettings of the 1st one

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-2022, appsettings

So, as titled, I've created a solution with 2 web api projects inside (quite simple)
I have configured the appsettings for each project, set the 2nd one as startup project
When I run the 2nd one in swagger, i've noticed my settings of the 2nd one are not taken into account and that it takes the settings from the 1st one
Any idea ?
Thanks for your kind help

I've tried changing projects settings and startup configuration but found no useful solution except moving the project to another solution

Comment: _"and that it takes the settings from the 1st one"_ - unlikely.  Care to post any evidence?  Delete the 1st one.  You'll soon know if it is really doing that.

Comment: Hi Deleted, I ran the 2nd project in debug mode and used the watch on Configuration to set section/keys that appear only in the first project appsettings and it's fine. When I use a section/key that appear only in the 2nd one I get nothing

Comment: For all we know you are using a junction point.  Please post screenshots of all build rules; post-deploy steps; deployment settings; folders; and app setting listings.  Hopefully you are not deploying both services to the same target folder

Comment: ok thanks I'll do that on monday, I don't have everything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click on the appsetting.json, and then select properties, there is a property called "Copy to output directory". Be sure you have it as "Copy always".

What could happen probably is the thing, that you made changes to both, but because it didn't include, it seems like it is using the one from the first one.

Hope this is your case.

Comment: Hi Jonáš, thanks a lot, it seems to work on my personal computer but I'll try it on my pro computer on monday. Best Regards

Comment: If it helps, you can tick my answer with green mark ✅.

Comment: hi Jonáš, I confirm it solved my problem. Have a nice week